# Дубликаты главных страниц modx

Tags: modx

Генерируются (если правильно выразился) страницы дублирующие главную.
К примеру можно прописать в адресной строке site.ru/articles/(любые символы) в итоге будет сгенерирована страница дублирующая главную, причем без css.
Как от этого избавиться?

Comment: Отправлять все левые запросы на 404 страницу, делается в .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте новый документ (страницу), которая будет выводиться при 404-ой ошибке. Затем в настройках системы найдите по ключу `error_page` параметр *Страница ошибки 404* и значением поставьте `id` созданного ранее документа.

По умолчанию, там как раз будет стоять значение `1` - что и есть главная страница.